# Why (in typescript 0.9.5) do I now get a bunch of "invalid new expression" errors? Example:

Tags: dojo, typescript, amd

Typescript 0.9.5 I now catching errors which were not reported in 0.9.1.  From dojo.d.ts:

```
declare module Dojo {
    class Color {
        constructor();
        constructor(colors: any[]);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var Color: Dojo.Color;
new Color([1,2,3]);
```

The error:

```
Invalid 'new' expression.
```

This error makes sense.  The solution seems to be to change the class to an interface.  This works:

```
declare module Dojo {
    interface Color {
        new();
        new(colors: any[]);
    }
}

var Color: Dojo.Color;
new Color([1, 2, 3]);
```

So my actual question is this...**what is a good pattern to follow for AMD style typescript coding?**  Here is what I have come up with to handle this particular example:

```
declare module Dojo {
    class Color {
    }

    interface IColor {
        new(): Color;
        new (colors: any[]): Color;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
require(["dojo/_base/Color", function (Color: Dojo.IColor) {    
    new Color([1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Or maybe there's a way to use the existing definition in dojo.d.ts?

Comment: Is the best pattern to use an interface for constructor and a class for everything else?
declare module Dojo {
    class Color {
        a: number;
        r: number;
        g: number;
        b: number;
    }

    interface IColor {
        new(): Color;
        new (colors: any[]): Color;
    }
}

var c: Dojo.IColor;
new c([1, 2, 3]);

Comment: ``function (Color: typeof Dojo.Color)`` will work fine.  I am not completely happy with the wierd syntax required though, but I guess it is unavoidable since JavaScript classes are simply function objects, and there must be a way to distinguish a class from a type.  Most other languages don't have this messy dual personalities, so for them it is safe to associate a class with a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is even friendlier for working with AMD than you think.  Assuming you're working with the d.ts file available [here](https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript/blob/master/dojo.d.ts), this is what your code should look like:

```
/// <reference path="./dojo.d.ts"/>

import Color = require("dojo/_base/Color");
var c = new Color([1, 2, 3]);
```

and this is what that compiles to:

```
define(["require", "exports", "dojo/_base/Color"], function(require, exports, Color) {
    var c = new Color([1, 2, 3]);
});
```

You can use multiple import statements in your code and the compiler will organize them for you.

You'll need to tell the compiler that it's the AMD module system you're using (and not commonjs) with the `-m AMD` command line switch or the `<TypeScriptModuleKind>amd</TypeScriptModuleKind>` property in your Visual Studio csproj.

---

**Edit:** Alternately you can use the [`typeof`](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/456796) type operator to refer to the shape of a module.

```
/// <reference path="./dojo.d.ts"/>

declare function require(name: string): any;

var Color: typeof Dojo.Color = require("dojo/_base/Color");
var c = new Color([1, 2, 3]);
```

This doesn't provide as much type safety as the above solution.

Comment: A good answer but I think this assumes an all-or-nothing commitment to typescript and a complete abandonment of the traditional require?  Is there a solution which does not use "import" and still does not modify dojo.d.ts?  I'm using esri.d.ts which does not have module defs and would therefore result in nested defines.  Also, I'm trying to limit my use of typescript to just type safety (my js should look like my ts without the type declarations).

Comment: I added another possible solution that I think gets you what you want, although I think it's not as good a solution.  The special syntax in the first solution doesn't look too much different but leaves less room for errors.  I'm not sure what "nested defines" means or why it's bad.

Comment: Love it!  Now I can require(["dojo/_base/color"], function (c: typeof Dojo.Color) {});  This is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: Regarding nested defines...if you put a define(["foo"]) after the import you will get a define within the outer define and this results in serializing trips to the server (bad).

Comment: Yes that makes sense and it is bad.  The "TypeScripty" way to do that is an ```export =``` statement.  That tells the compiler what you want exported from the module and a ```define``` is generated instead of a ```require```.

Answer (score 1):

This usage

```
var Color: Dojo.Color;
new Color([1,2,3]);
```

throws an error because you are declaring the variable `Color` without assigning a value it, which means that `Color` will be `undefined`. `undefined` does not have a constructor. I believe that you are wanting to do this instead:

```
new Dojo.Color([1,2,3]);
```

Note that this

```
var c: Dojo.IColor;
new c([1, 2, 3]);
```

will compile but will fail at runtime. You've told the compiler that `c` has a constructor by giving it a type that says it has a constructor, but it is really `undefined` so it will fail during runtime.

To answer your question: classes and interfaces have completely different roles. All an interface does is specify typing information. A class is something that you can call a constructor on.

Comment: You are correct of course.  My question left out too many details.  What I'm looking for is a pattern to assign types to the dojo framework.  I will revise the question to indicate what I'm really doing (which is require(["dojo/_base/Color"], function (Color: Dojo.Color) {...}).